# Having different background images for different views in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, uiview

I'm new to angularJS and i'm trying to have different backgrounds for different pages. But i'm having difficulty since i have my view tied to some elements in my index.html.

index.html

```
<div class="top-container">
        <div class="navigation" >
            <nav>....</nav>
        </div>
        <div ui-view="topContent"></div>
</div>
```

The ui-view injects new content for each page which is tied to the nav element. I currently have one background for the entire site using

```
.top-container{
    background-image: url('bg.jpeg');
   }
```

Any ideas how i can change the background for different pages? Any way i can pass some variable or something to change the bg image based on the page i'm on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Firstly, set the background on every view.

```
$stateProvider.state("home",
            {
                templateUrl: "/scripts/app/home/home.html",
                url: "/home",
                controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                data: {
                    background: 'home'
                }
            })
            .state("login",
            {
                templateUrl: "/scripts/app/login/login.html",
                url: "/login",
                controller: 'LoginCtrl',
                data: {
                    background: 'login'
                }
            });
```

Now grab that setting on every state change and put it in the root scope.

```
app.run([
    '$rootScope', function($rootScope)
    {

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState)
        {
            $rootScope.background = toState.data.background;
        });
    }
]);
```

Now in the HTML set your background from the root scope on whatever element you want. Mind you, this has to be inside your ng-app declaration.

```
<body ng-class="background">
```

And that is the beauty of Angular for you.

Also, this is my go-to solution for anything that changes for every state. Like page title for starters..

Comment: I've added background to my states. I tried to assign the $rootscope.background to the value passed in from the states in my controller, i get an undefined error background. Also, how do you add the two bg images in css? Do you use .home{background-image:"a.jpeg"} and .login {background-image:"b.jpeg"}?

Comment: Here is a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/0bSnMF5nLONP9i1lQCWZ?p=preview   Ideally, you will use classes to do the background changes. It is quite simple really.

Comment: it works now! i didn't inject the event parameter earlier which was throwing the error

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class directive

```
ng-class="{'class1': yourvalue == 'something' || yourvalue  == 'somethingelse'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ngStyle` for your CSS class. [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)
is the demo plunker for changing color.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add new class name on .top-container div when view changed.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
   ... you could trigger something here ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $routeChangeStart listener, which will be fired every time you try to switch to a different route/view.

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
    if(current.loadedTemplateUrl.indexOf("/call") > -1){
       // set the required background image 
    }else if(current.loadedTemplateUrl.indexOf("/login") > -1){
       // set the required background image 
    }
});
```

You can use javascript to set your background image or **ng-class**. For example

```
ng-class="{'one': url == '/login'}"
```

**Note: Don't forget to add background-image property to your class.**